# I have been getting error that there function contactDeleteById requires param @contactID but i dont think there is any problem with my code below

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

Below is my sql code:-

```
ALTER PROC [dbo].[ContactDeleteByID]
@ContactID int
AS
 BEGIN
         DELETE FROM contact
         WHERE ContactID = @ContactID
 END
```

Below is my C# code:-(which i have written correctly for sure)

```
protected void btndelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (sqlCon.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
    sqlCon.Open();
    SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("ContactDeleteByID",sqlCon);
    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ContactID", Convert.ToInt32(hfcontactID.Value));
    sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    sqlCon.Close();
    Clear();
    FillGridView();
    lblsuccessmessage.Text = "Deleted Successfully";
}
```

Comment: Tell us your exception and more details of your failure.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are getting this because the  @ContactID is not nullable. You need to initialize it to null.

Try this:

```
 @ContactID int=null
```

So your SP should be like this:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    GO
    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
    GO
    ALTER PROC [dbo].[ContactDeleteByID]
    @ContactID int = null
    AS
        
     BEGIN
             DELETE FROM contact
             WHERE ContactID = @ContactID
             END
```

Comment: Would you please elaborate a bit more on this! Sorry if it was easy to understand i didnt get it

Comment: @CodeJunkie, when it says `contactDeleteById requires param @ContactID` it is looking for value of @ContactID which resides in `hfcontactID.Value` Hiddenfield. Currently you are getting null value for `hfcontactID.Value` and since @ContactID in your SP is not initialized with default value null (as I showed in my answer), your application is expecting the value. This has generated a conflict and that's why it is throwing the error.

Comment: You are getting null value instead of some actual value in `hfcontactID.Value`. If the value is null, your data won't get delete, because it won't get ContactID based on which you are deleting the data. Now, it's your job to find the reason why value in hiddenfield i.e. in `hfcontactID.Value` is null.

Comment: love you loads man! It worked out finally. was on it since a last few days. Once again thanks a million for the support and clarification

Comment: @CodeJunkie I am glad it helped :)

Answer (score 1):

You are not telling your command that it is executing a stored procedure. All you are realling doing is executing the following TSQL:

```
ContactDeleteByID
```

Which is executing the procedure, but as you are not passing the @ContractID parameter, which is required it throws an error.

You have two options, firstly explicitly state that "ContactDeleteByID" is a stored procedure, e.g.

```
SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("ContactDeleteByID",sqlCon);
sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
```

Alternatively, you could change your SQL to include the parameter, e.g.

```
SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("EXECUTE ContactDeleteByID @ContractID",sqlCon);
```

This would actually work without `EXECUTE` but I would implore you not to take this shortcut, as this makes the intent much clearer.

As an aside, I'd [advise against using `AddWithValue`](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/), instead supply your data type explicitly, e.g.

```
sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@ContactID", SqlDbType.Int.Value).Value = Convert.ToInt32(hfcontactID.Value);
```

Comment: Thanks a ton for the elaborative explanantion. I have finally resolved my error. Very supportive of you